# Trying to Call a REST Web Service API from an HTML page in another project and GET an item's properties

Tags: javascript, rest, api, web-services, get

I have one project that holds my REST web service API and another project that serves at my front-end.  I want to enter a unique ID in an html text box and use that ID when calling the API to retrieve that ID's properties.  I'm trying to use  JavaScript to make the call to the Route that I have for the API call, but no luck.

My API controller has the call I'm trying to make:

```
<Route("orders/{id}/contents")>
<HttpGet>
Public Function GetOrderContents(ByVal id As String) As SPFolderOver

Dim retValue As ReturnVal
retValue = GetOrderInformation(id)
Dim ex = New Sharepoint()
Dim t = ex.GetOrderContent(retValue.Year, retValue.SONumber)
Dim myT = New SPFolderOver()
myT = SPFolderOver.LoadFolder(t)
myT.FolderName = t.Name

Return myT

End Function
```

My HTML with my JavaScript Function:

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function getContents() {
      var on = document.getElementById("orderNumber").value


        $.get(window.location.href = "http://localhost:54754/orders/{id}/contents"), $.get("orders/{id}/contents"), $("{id}").replaceWith(on);
      }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="eDocForm">
    <div>
      <input type="text" id="orderNumber" />
      <input id="submitOrder" onclick="getContents()" type="submit" title="Submit" />
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your $.get does not look right. Try something like this:

```
$.get( "http://localhost:54754/orders/" + on + "/contents", 
       function( data ) {   
         // do something here with the returned data...
         // alert( data );
});
```

You probably did not intent to submit the form, so change from:

```
<input id="submitOrder" onclick="getContents()" type="submit" title="Submit" />
```

to something like:

```
<input id="submitOrder" onclick="getContents()" type="button" title="Submit" />
```

I did not review your server side code as the functions, etc. are not fully defined there.